# Die roll - Geometric distribution

Tags: probability

The question is:

> I throw a die until I get the number 6 three times. What's the variance of the total die rolls?

Is this just the Variance of  Geometric distribution $(1-p)/p^2$ where $p=1/6$?

Comment: probability of getting six in consecutively three times is not 1/6 at all this is the probability of getting six for a throw, before the variance you have to find probability correctly

Comment: "I need to find the variance of these events...". Events do not have a variance. Random variables have.

Comment: What does it mean to get "three-six consecutively"? Do you want to get $3$ and then $6$, or do you want to get three $6$s consecutively?

Comment: Sorry, someone edited it. What I meant and edited back now, Is that I want to get three times the number 6.

Comment: So not necessarily consecutive sixes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the sixes are not demanded to be consecutive then the number of rolls can be writtens as: $$R=R_1+R_2+R_3$$ where $R_1$ stands for the number of rolls needed to arrive at the first six, $R_2$ for the number of rolls after that needed to arrive at the second six and $R_3$ for the number of rolls after that needed to arrive at the second six.

The $R_i$ are iid and have geometric distribution with parameter $p=\frac16$.

Now apply that the variance of the summation of independent variables equals the summation of variances.

---

If the sixes must be consecutive then please let me know. In that case I will delete this answer.